# My 5.15.0-71 kernel on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on AMD Ryzen 3 2200g can never boot

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, amd-ryzen

I installed the 5.15.0-71 kernel on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and at some point, I noticed that when I boot my AMD Ryzen 3 2200g desktop, I get the GRUB menu after:

```
error: cannot allocate kernel buffer
error: you need to load the kernel first.
Press any key to continue..._ 

[something something backup not working either]
Press any key to continue..._
```

Secure Boot is off, and I only have integrated graphics.

Unlike [the other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465460/after-kernel-update-error-cannot-allocate-kernel-buffer-you-need-to-load-kern), the one about a Ryzen 7600 system, I'm not having just a *majority* of boot attempts being failures, I've *never* gotten the kernel to boot.

Does it matter that my 5.15.0-70 kernel works fine, except for getting the [ACPI Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot/1333162#1333162)?

Also, my GRUB file for update-grub is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=30
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Timing out for far longer than the [known working for some, of 5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2017929/comments/10). No dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Lenovo IdeaPas 1.  After reading the posts none of the suggestions worked.  However, people were talking about graphics cards so I thought I'd just try blindly playing around with grub settings.

Uncommenting this line only worked for me:

GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

I tried 1920x1280 and this didn't work, but 1024x768 does.

Hope this helps to get others booting and gives those how know what they are doing a pointer :)

Comment: tried "GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768". Yep, this works! Thanks!